# Django pagination of large image thumbnails

Tags: django, pagination

I have a couple hundred of image thumbnails, 15k each. I want to display 20 or so on each page.

Would `django.core.paginator` suffice for the pagination of these pages? I.e., will it return only those images displayed on the current page? (And if not, what would be a good way to do this?) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends, because there is one big limitation from the RDBMS (which affects all databases, including MySQL, Postgres, etc.).

`django.core.paginator` takes a `QuerySet` which represent any kind of SQL query and adds a `LIMIT` clause to just get a couple of entries from the database. This approach works well for many kinds of applications, but might become a serious problem if you have a lot of entries. The particular problem is, that whenever you access the 800th page, the database will actually fetch 801*20 entries and then drop the first 800*20 entries again to return the last twenty.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to solve this problem. In a lot of cases, a next/prev button might be enough so you can write your own pagination which does operate on after-keys instead of page numbers. For example, if the last entry currently displayed by the user has the key `"D"` you show a next button which links to `/next?after=D` and then use a SQL query like `SELECT * FROM objects WHERE key >`D`ORDER BY key  LIMIT 20`. The advantage of this approach is, that you can add an index on `objects.key` which speed up things significantly.

The other approach requires, that you add an additional, indexed (!) column `page_num` to your table. Then you can perform SQL queries like `SELECT * FROM objects WHERE page_num=800 ORDER BY key`. With that approach, you can still access all pages randomly, but you have to maintain the page_num column. This might be easy if data is mostly appended at the end and is more complicated if you want to delete/insert elements from the middle efficiently.

So, I would start with `django.core.paginator` because it's just about 1 line of code. But keep an eye on the response times of your paginated views and the slowquery log from your database. If your database server can't handle the load anymore, you will have to choose one of the techniques mentioned above. Choose solution 2 if random page access is an requirement and solution 1 otherwise (because it's much simpler).

PS: And yes, `django.core.paginator` will work correctly. :)